# How to translate FYI into Japanese

Tags: translation

I'm not interested in translateling just the literal meaning of FYI. I'm interested in if there is a phrase that fits the same nuance.

Some English examples.

To Spouse: "Oh, FYI, Jill is bringing the wine".

To Co-Worker: "FYI, that meeting has been moved to 4pm"

To A Friend: "FYI, the Toyoko-Line is closed for repairs so you should probably take the Meguro-Line"

"FYI" is a very casual phrase in the situations above.  Maybe "ところで。。。。”? Although I don't know if you can use "ところで。。。” at the start of the conversation. Every example I've been taught is always in the middle of a conversation when wanting to suddenly switch topics.

I came here because I typed "FYI" into Google translate and it said "ご参考までに” was the "community verified" translation but that seems not to fit the same nuance as FYI.

Comment: my two cents: ご参考までに is more like when you are in an office setting and you send an email, etc to someone, then there is someone else that does not need to take any action into the issue, but needs to be aware of the progress. It conveys the more "formal" nuance of the expression, imo.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `ちなみに` aka "by the way" in the same context as FYI in a casual setting.

Comment: Do you mean [ち]{L}なみに?

Comment: Can you explain how ちなみに、ところで、and ご参考までに differ?

Comment: @istrasci good catch, edited.  thanks!